# How to add array of objects to angular form

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Let's say I have a json with these values:

```
{
car: bmw,
tunes : [{
 name: turbo,
 cost: 350
},
{
 name: exhaust,
 cost: 100
}]
}
```

How do I create a form that will be able to take these values?
FormGroup won't work I think. FormArray seems like the right thing to use but I haven't seen it being used with pre selected fields that can be assigned values to, which is what I need. I need to be able to assign array of object to the from, edit certain values of the objects and export the form as a json with the array of objects (same as the array came but maybe with different values). The fields wont change so I don't need to add them dynamically, I just need to assign them.

My imagined solution would look something like this:

```
form: New FormGroup({
 car: new FormControl(),
 tunes: new FormArray([
  name: new FormControl(),
  cost: new FormControl()
 ])
})
```

**Update:**

This seems to be the wanted solution:

```
form: New FormGroup({
     car: new FormControl(),
     tunes: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
       name: new FormControl(),
       cost: new FormControl()
      })
     ])
    })
```

but it gives me error: "Cannot find form control at index 1"

When I look at the json it produces, it is the wanted outcome but I'm not able to assign values right now.

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#usage-notes

Comment: @R.Richards That's interesting because that gave me an error. I will try it again

Comment: Well, yes but is there a way for those form controls to have a key? That is my main problem. I need it to be an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

export interface ITune {
  name: string;
  cost: string;
}

export interface Icar {
  car: string;
  tunes: ITune[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html'
})

export class ListOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  public validator: { [key: string]: ValidatorFn | null };
  public data: Icar;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.validator = {
      name: Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])
    };
    this.data = {
      car: 'bmw',
      tunes: [
        { name: 'turbo', cost: '100$' },
        { name: 'exhaust', cost: '200$' }
      ]
    };
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.createFormGroup(this.fb, this.data, {});
    this.form.addControl(
      'tunes',
      new FormArray(this.addTunes(this.data.tunes))
    );
  }

  public addTunes(tunes: ITune[]): FormGroup[] {
    const formGroups: FormGroup[] = [];
    tunes.forEach(x => {
      const formGroup = this.createFormGroup(this.fb, x, this.validator);
      formGroups.push(formGroup);
    });
    return formGroups;
  }

  createFormGroup<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(
    formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    dataSource: T,
    validators: { [key: string]: ValidatorFn | null }
  ): FormGroup {
    // dynamic creation of form control by enumerating the object
    const config: any = {};
    Object.keys(dataSource).forEach((propertyName: string) => {
      const fieldVlidators = validators[propertyName];
      const value = dataSource[propertyName];
      if (!(value instanceof Array)) {
        if (fieldVlidators !== undefined) {
          config[propertyName] = [value, fieldVlidators];
        } else if (fieldVlidators !== undefined) {
          config[propertyName] = [value, fieldVlidators];
        } else {
          config[propertyName] = [value];
        }
      }
    });
    const group = formBuilder.group(config);
    return group;
  }
}
```

You can use .addControl() method to add control on the formGroup. createFormGroup() is a generalized method that you can use to create the formgroup. You can also pass the validator in that if you need to validate any control. You just need to pass the object with name and validator rule in createFormGroup() function.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it is working for you

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but from my first impression it looks like you are trying to create it dynamically and it looks very complicated, that is not I'm trying to achieve. I'm looking for a simple solution to assign array of objects to from and be able to export the form as a json with array of objects too while also being able to edit specific field and specific objects in the array.